# Как вывести кол-во просмотров постов wordpress на главной?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я установил плагин Wp Post Views , у меня появилось свойство у записей - Views, как на скриншоте.
Как мне вывести это свойство на главной странице?

```
$news = GetPosts($staty_id, 'date');
<?foreach ($news as $key => $item) {?>

<div class="blog-main-item-link">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($item->ID); ?>">
                  Подробнее
                </a>
                <span>
                    <div class="eye-ico-block">
        <?echo do_shortcode('[WPPV-TOTAL-VIEWS]');?>
                    </div>
                </span>

<?}?>
```

Вот таким кодом я вывожу записи(новости) на главной. По инструкции плагина вставляю этот шорткод, но он для отдельной записи поста, если я его добавляю на главную, то счетчик просмотров общий для всех, а мне нужно чтобы для каждой записи показывал своё кол-во просмотров.

Как мне вывести вот это свойство записей Views для каждой записи отдельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому надо. Плагин Post Views Counter. В коде выводим кол-во просмотров для каждой отдельной записи.

https://wp-system.ru/sozdanie-sayta/plaginyi-dlya-wordpress/schyotchik-prosmotrov-v-wordpress/

```
$news = GetPosts($staty_id, 'date');
 <?foreach ($news as $key => $item) {?>
<? echo pvc_get_post_views($item->ID)?>
<?}?>
```